# Performance scrolling and retina resolution images in CALayer

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIView that is placed as a subview in a UIScrollView. I have several child views made up of images, text, and buttons in the UIView. In order to get decent scrolling performance I set `shouldRasterize = YES` on the layer in the UIView. This worked great in that performance increased so I have smooth scrolling and doesn't pose an issue since my graphics are static once drawn. However, the problem is that when I set shouldRasterize that the rasterized graphics are blurry and low resolution on a Retina display. Is there a way to have high resolution graphics that are rasterized for performance?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Seems I needed to set rasterizationScale to the proper value for the device as follows.

```
myView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Comment: Does the parent layer also need to use the same rasterizationScale or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem-- a rotated `UIView` with several `UIImageView` subviews. When I set the `rasterizationScale = 2.0`, the images became crisper, but this caused serration to reemerge. To fix this, I created a `containerView` that held the `UIView` and `UIIMageView`s (which were previously subviews of the UIView) and applied `rasterizationScale = 1.0` to the `UIView` and `rasterizationScale = 2.0` to the `UIImageView`s. Now everything looks quite nice.

Comment: I suggest to use the much simpler solution suggested by timeuser.

Answer (score 0):

@Jamie Hamick's answer in Swift 5:

myView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale